# Template function lookup

Tags: c++, templates

Consider this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename A>
void foo(A& a) {
    std::cout << "the wrong foo" << std::endl;
}

template<typename A>
void do_stuff(A& a) {
    foo(a);
}

template<typename X>
void foo(std::vector<X>& a) {
    std::cout << "the right foo" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> q;
    do_stuff(q);
}
```

Why is it calling the "wrong" foo? If the first declaration of foo is removed the right foo is called.

I am using gcc 4.6.3.

**Update:**
If functions are declared in the following order, the right foo is called.

```
template<typename A> void do_stuff(A& a) { ... }
template<typename A> void foo(A& a) { ... }
template<typename X> void foo(std::vector<X>& a) { ... }
```

Comment: hmmmm, in VS2005 it prints 'the right foo'

Comment: It's due to the order in which you declare the two `foo`s. Try placing "the right foo" above "the wrong foo" and see what happens. I think that (and someone please correct me if I'm wrong) `do_stuff` shouldn't even know that "the right foo" exists, because it's not predeclared. Still, I'm curious to find out which `foo` has precedence and why if both are predeclared.

Comment: As `do_stuff` is first 'instantiated' in `main`, it should see both `foo`s.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic That's a good point, sir! :) +1

Comment: @Mihai: This is not true because do_stuff is instantiated in main where both declarations of foo are available. As indiciated, if the first declaration of foo is removed it runs fine. In this case foo is declared after do_stuff and everything is well.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic: "in VS2005 it prints 'the right foo'" - that's because that compiler has it's own, non-standard, ideas about name lookup from templates. Non-dependent names *should* be bound when the template is defined, not when it's instantiated; so GCC is correct to bind to the "wrong" `foo`. MSVC erroneously binds all names when the template is instantiated.

Comment: @Mike, yes, you are right, the answer from mitchnull points to the part of the standard I was trying to locate for last half an hour :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The observed behavior is correct, as `foo(a)` is a type dependent expression according to:

```
14.6.2.2 Type-dependent expressions                         [temp.dep.expr]

1) Except as described below, an expression is type-dependent if any
   subexpression is type-dependent.

2) this is type-dependent if the class type of the enclosing member
   function is dependent (14.6.2.1).

3) An id-expression is type-dependent if it contains

    — an identifier associated by name lookup with one or more declarations 
      declared with a dependent type,
    ...
```

and under 14.6.4 (Dependent name resoultion):

```
14.6.4.2 Candidate functions                              [temp.dep.candidate]

For a function call that depends on a template parameter, the candidate
functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3) except
that:

— For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1) or qualified
  name lookup (3.4.3), only function declarations from the template definition 
  context are found.
— For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function
  declarations found in either the template definition context or the template
  instantiation context are found.

If the function name is an unqualified-id and the call would be ill-formed or
would find a better match had the lookup within the associated namespaces
considered all the function declarations with external linkage introduced in
those namespaces in all translation units, not just considering those
declarations found in the template definition and template instantiation
contexts, then the program has undefined behavior.
```

The "wrong" `foo()` is picked because that's the only one visible at *the point of template definition*, and the "right" `foo()` is not considered because it's not in a *namespace associated with the types of the function arguments*.

If you modify your code so that the "right" `foo()` would be in an associated namespace, it would be picked instead of the "wrong" `foo()`. (In this particular case, it's not allowed by the standard, so don't do the below, but with your own namespace / types this is how it should work)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename A> void foo(A& a)
{
    std::cout << "the wrong foo" << std::endl;
}

template<typename A>
void do_stuff(A& a) {
    foo(a);
}

namespace std { // evil, don't do this with namespace std!

template<typename X>
void foo(std::vector<X>& a) {
    std::cout << "the right foo" << std::endl;
}

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> q;
    do_stuff(q); // calls the "right" foo()
}
```

Comment: Except that `foo` is a non-dependent name.

Comment: @Mike Seymour it is, because of the argument of type `A` (which is a dependent type). I'll add the relevant parts from the standard

Comment: No it isn't. The name `foo` does not depend on `A`; `A` just determines which specialisation of `foo` is to be used once the name has been bound.

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice that the part I read only applied to id-expressions. (and I just found the same example you gave in your answer that clearly defines this behavior :)

Comment: Alright, it's not a dependent name, but a dependent expression. I'll edit again...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation regarding the namespace. Actually I was using some similar techniques as in boost::graph, but there instead of std::vector a user defined type is used. For this case, there are, as you explained, additional lookup rules and I was wandering what was wrong in my code ...

Comment: @mitchnull According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42729778/9784373), it seems like the resolution for `foo(a);` is delayed till the type of `a` in `do_stuff()` is known, which is when compiler sees `do_stuff(q);` in `main()`.  At that point, I thought both versions of  template function `foo()` are visible to the compiler.  But you stated, "The "wrong" foo() is picked because that's the only one visible at the point of template definition".  Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @HCSF I believe this happens in the adl example because the second `adl()` function is an overload and not a template function.

Answer (score 3):

Within a template definition, name lookup for a non-dependent name (that is, one like `foo` that doesn't depend on the template parameters) is performed where the template is defined, not where it's instantiated. This is specified by the standard:

> C++11 14.6.3 Non-dependent names used in a template definition are found using the usual name lookup and bound at the point they are used.

and illustrated by an example similar to yours:

```
void g(double);
void h();

template<class T> class Z {
public:
  void f() {
    g(1);           // calls g(double)
    h++;            // ill-formed: cannot increment function;
                    // this could be diagnosed either here or
                    // at the point of instantiation
  }
};

void g(int);        // not in scope at the point of the template
                    // definition, not considered for the call g(1)
```

Regarding your update: I believe that, with both `foo` declarations placed after `do_stuff`, the program should be ill-formed, and GCC is incorrect to (apparently) defer lookup until the point of instantiation when it fails at the point of use.

**UPDATE:** As noted in the comments, this behaviour is indeed incorrect, and was fixed in gcc-4.7.

Comment: I found something in the [release notes for GCC 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html). This is a bug in 4.6...

Comment: 4.7.1 behaves correctly, rejecting the code with *error: 'foo' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]*: http://liveworkspace.org/code/74ea0fb26620348fece64b8f00ac1970

Comment: @Danvil that's quite a document to look through; the item is the bullet "*G++ now correctly implements the two-phase lookup rules [...]*"

Comment: That example is a bit misleading, as the call to `g(1)` doesn't depend on the template parameters. Later in `14.6.4.2 Candidate functions` a better explanation is given for this situation. See my (revised) answer

Answer (score 2):

When you call `do_stuff` the type of `a` is `std::vector<int>`. The compiler then searches for a `foo` that takes `std::vector<int>` and finds that it can use `foo(A&)` (the 'wrong' `foo`), `foo(std::vector<B>&)` has yet to be declared. If you remove this declaration you should get a compiler error as templates must be defined before they are used. If you don't it may be down to a bug in the template system of gcc rather than a feature of the language. Try it with `clang++` and you should see:

```
test.cpp:6:5: error: call to function 'foo' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by
  argument-dependent lookup
foo(a);
^
```

EDIT: It seems that this is actually an error in the way `clang++` deals with templates, it should be able to resolve the call to the second `foo` that appears before the instantiation of the template.

Comment: This is not correct. As you say, templates must be defined before they are used. But do_stuff is first used in main, and only at this point is the template instantiated. Before this usage the compiler does not care about the actual contents of the template.

Comment: Ok, looks like that is a bug in `clang`'s template system then.

Comment: @David: It doesn't care about the contents of the template, but it cares about the *existence* of the template. Right `foo` and wrong `foo` are two independent templates, and at the point of declaration of `do_stuff`, where the compiler determines what `foo` refers to, only the "wrong" one is available.

Comment: @sth: If you remove the first declaration of foo it works fine and the compiler takes the second also it is declared after do_stuff.

Comment: @sth: So the template can only choose to resolve the calls within it to template functions that are declared before the definition of the template, but this is done at the point that the template is first instantiated? I may well be wrong but that's what I thought was supposed to happen.

Comment: This is correct - `foo` is a non-dependent name, so it's bound at the point of use in the template definition, not at the point of instantiation.

Comment: So I see the mistake now. My judgement was guided by what GCC accepts as correct code and not what is actually stated in the standard. I though that non-dependent names are treated like dependent names, but this is not the case and GCC 4.6 has a bug there.