# name lookup rules in template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void adl(T)
{
  cout << "T";
}

struct S
{
};

template<typename T>
void call_adl(T t)
{
  adl(S());
  adl(t);
}

void adl(S)
{
  cout << "S";
}

int main ()
{
  call_adl(S());
}
```

Why the result is "TS"? What is the name lookup rule inside template function?

http://ideone.com/sB3DnL

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Templates are compiled in two phases, at the point of definition and the point of instantiation. The first phase happens when the template definition is first processed by the compiler, and some names are bound to definitions right away. Some names are left unbound until the template is instantiated, because they depend on template parameters and so cannot be looked up until the template is instantiated and the template arguments are known.

In this call:

```
adl(S());
```

There is nothing that is *dependent* on the template parameters of the function, so the lookup is done right away (during the first phase) and it finds the only function called `adl` that is in scope at that point.

In this call:

```
adl(t);
```

it is *dependent* on the type of `t` and so lookup is delayed until instantiation when the type of `t` is known. When you call `call_adl(S())` the second overload of `adl` is in scope, and so when the `adl(t)` call performs name lookup there is another function in scope, and it's a better match for the arguments.

Comment: So the definition of 'void adl(S)' is not seen by the compiler in the phase I?

Comment: @q0987 No, because it is declared between the definition and instantiation of `call_adl`.

Comment: @user1937198, after I moved the 'void adl(S)' below the 'main' function. The result is still 'TS'. In other words, at the time of instantiation, the 'void adl(S)' is not in scope yet. then why the result is 'TS'? http://ideone.com/BApxuL

Comment: [temp.point] p8 "The end of the translation unit is also considered a point of instantiation" i.e. all declarations in the file can be visible during phase 2.

Comment: you stated, "when the `adl(t)` call performs name lookup there is another function in scope, and it's a better match for the arguments".  Is `void adl(S)` a better match because it is a plain old non template function?  As Herb Sutter [suggested](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) that plain old non template function is preferred when a template function is equally matched?

Comment: @HCSF, yes. In the standard [over.match.best] p2 says "a viable function `F1` is defined to be a _better_ function than another viable function `F2` if [they are otherwise equivalent and] `F1` is not a function template specialization and `F2` is a function template specialization, ...".

Comment: @JonathanWakely in that case, it is strange that I changed `void adl(S)` to `void adl(bool)` and `call_adl(S())` to `call_adl(false);`, and the template function is called for `adl(t)`.  I have created a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62787564/function-resolution-and-ordering).

Comment: @HCSF there is no ADL for built-in types like `bool`