# function resolution and ordering

Tags: c++

Program A

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void bar(T) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    bar(t);
    bar(true);
}

void bar(bool) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    foo(false); // void foo(T) [T = bool], void bar(T) [T = bool], void bar(T) [T = bool]
    // however, after I moved bar(S) definition forward right before foo(), it printed void foo(T) [T = S], void bar(bool) and then void bar(bool)
}
```

Program B

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void bar(T) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

struct S{};

template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    bar(t);
    bar(S());
}

void bar(S) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    foo(S()); // printed void foo(T) [T = S], void bar(S) and then void bar(T) [T = S]
    // however, after I moved bar(S) definition forward right before foo(), it printed void foo(T) [T = S], void bar(S) and then void bar(S)

}
```

According to [this article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm), a plain old non-template function should be selected.  However, program A and program B tells me:

1. Ordering of functions matters
2. Classes of types (built-in vs user defined) matters

What are the exact rules used here?

I tried clang 10 and gcc 10.  Same outputs.

Thanks.

===========================

Edit:
@1201ProgramAlarm suggested this a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729586/name-lookup-rules-in-template-function).

And the answer there indeed answers why functions' order matters for program B.  However, it doesn't answer why replacing `struct S` with `bool` the function resolution will be different (see program B).

Based on that answer, let's look at program B, because `bar(t)` depends on the template parameter `T`, and so the function resolution will be delayed to phase 2 (template instantiation), then when compiler sees `foo(false)`, it knows `T` is `bool` in `foo(T)`.  Then, compiler is able to do the function resolution at the end of the translation unit (phase 2?), but why did compiler choose the function template version given [this](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)?  Shouldn't a plain old non template function be chosen?  Compiler does so for Program A tho.

But Clang and GCC don't follow that rules suggested by the article nor the answer in the other post.  Likely I missed something.

Comment: Built-in types can’t trigger ADL, so there is no forward lookup to perform in that case.  Isn’t that the only issue here?

Comment: Yeah it's an ADL thing. Changing `bar` to `::bar` makes the behavior consistent.

Comment: @DavisHerring @Pubby would you guys mind elaborating the sequence of lookups in both program A and B?  I just tried to move `template<typename T> bar(T)` after `template<typename T> foo(T)`, and then g++ complains `no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation`.  So it seems like ADL still kicks in even though at the end `T` is deduced to `bool`, a built-in type.

Comment: In program A, when compiler sees `bar(t)`, it defers the name lookup as `t` depends on `T` in `Foo()` and it is not known yet.  When compiler sees `bar(true)`, the name lookup is done right away -- matching `template <typename T> void bar(T)`, and then when the compiler sees `foo(false)`, `void foo(bool)` is instantiated (i.e. `T` is known), then `bar(t)` can perform the lookup, at that time, both `template <typename T> void bar(T)` (which is instantiated as well?) and `void bar(bool)` are in scope

Comment: and since `template <typename T> void bar(T)` is declared first and so name lookup will stop there and pick up `template <typename T> void bar(T)`?

Comment: Don’t think about this in terms of *time*, just space.  The lookup finds things declared before the template definition, and additionally those functions declared later (which must be before the instantiation) that are found by ADL for the ultimate types.  That latter set is simply empty in the built-in case (which produces the error you quoted from GCC).  Is there really a mystery here worth an answer beyond those to other similar questions?